# How to share DotNetNuke content across multiple pages?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have just created a new DotNetNuke 6 website. The default installation has a social links area which is on each page. Can I change the contents of the social links (e.g set the Facebook href) in one central place or do I have to go to each page and edit the contents in each place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DotNetNuke has a notion of referencing modules that would come in handy here. Essentially you can drop a new module on the page and configure it as you please, then go to another page and instead of dropping a new module, you select an existing module from another page. Now each of the modules appear to be separate, but are actually just the same module appearing in different places. You can then edit the module and the content will change across pages. *

To answer your question specifically - I don't believe this is how the default content is set up. You would need to go in and delete all of them (save one) and then reference the remaining elsewhere.

[image: Add existing module in DotNetNuke]

A couple of notes:

This behavior isn't absolute across all modules, technically each module gets to decide how it's content is shared across pages. Most modules, and notably the text/html module, work how I described, but some more advanced modules may not.

Additionally, the "copy module" option in the photo above will create a new module based on the original. If you don't have copy module selected, no new module will be created, the existing one will simply be referenced.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try and feedback later